# MYSQL query select count fields

Tags: mysql, select, count

```
select *, count(*) as total
from customer_data
where category = 'Fashion'
group by customer_id
order by total desc
```

From this result of query how could i take fields where total > 5?

Comment: `having count(*) > 5`. google `sql having`

Comment: Select * and group by may be not show the data you expect.

Comment: post also customer_data table definition. you probably need to change to select customer_id ( not * )

Answer (score 1):

You need a `HAVING` clause. Also try not to select nonaggregated columns or columns that are not in `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT aa.*, _aa.total
FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM customer_data
    WHERE category = 'Fashion'
    GROUP BY customer_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
) AS _aa
INNER JOIN customer_data AS aa
ON _aa.customer_id = aa.customer_id
ORDER BY _aa.total DESC
```

Have a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and [here](http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/).